# How do I capture the URI from a registerActivityResult?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm currently attempting to write a view in an android app that will open a camera on a button press, let the user record a video, and stash the URI in a member attached to said view. I'm very hopeful this is possible, but unsure because I can't find many docs regarding the issue.

I'm using the top answer here as a reference for capturing the URI, and it's very comprehensive, but not working in my case for reasons of which I am unsure.

I declare my variable at the top of the file as so

`private var videoUri: Uri? = null`

The rest of the relevant code happens here:

```
val recordVideoResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo()) { uri: Uri? ->
    uri?.let {
        this.videoUri = uri
    }
}

val requestPermissionLauncher = registerForActivityResult(
    ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission()
) { isGranted: Boolean ->
    if (isGranted) {
        launchCamera()
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't open camera because permission is denied. Please provide access in settings.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}


fun launchCamera() {
    if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_ANY)) { // First check if camera is available in the device
        when {
            ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> {
                recordVideoResult.launch(this.uri)
            }
            else -> {
                // You can directly ask for the permission.
                // The registered ActivityResultCallback gets the result of this request.
                requestPermissionLauncher.launch(
                    Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My IDE and compiler yell at me with the below error, which looks like a bug to me, but will not go away.
[image]

I'm very unsure what I'm doing wrong. Forgive me if it's incredibly obvious, I've been writing Kotlin for less than a week.

Comment: What is your import for the `Uri` class? Is it the right one?

Comment: @ianhanniballake I *think* it's the right one because it's the only one I can find. The line is `import android.net.Uri`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the input and output of `CaptureVideo` mixed up. The [`CaptureVideo` contract](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo) says:

> An `ActivityResultContract` to take a video saving it into the provided content-`Uri`.
>
> Returns `true` if the video was saved into the given Uri.

So the **input** is a `Uri` - that's what you need to pass to `launch`. The **output** is a `Boolean`. This can be confirmed by looking at the [class itself](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-main:activity/activity/src/main/java/androidx/activity/result/contract/ActivityResultContracts.kt;l=340?ss=androidx&q=CaptureVideo), which shows the complete type - `ActivityResultContract<Uri, Boolean>`.

This means what you actually need to do is:

1. [Setup a `FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/training/secure-file-sharing/setup-sharing). This is how you generate a `Uri` from a `File` that your app owns that is suitable to send to the `launch` of a `CaptureVideo` Intent. You're the one who picks where the video is stored, not the camera app.
2. Generate the appropriate `File` associated with where you want to save your video and store it as a variable in your class like you were previously doing with your `videoUri`, e.g., in a variable named `file` (as per the [note on the Launching an Intent documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result#launch), you'll probably also want to store that in `onSaveInstanceState()` in case your process is destroyed while the camera is up).
3. Use the `FileProvider` APIs to generate a Uri from your `File` and pass that to your call to `launch`.

```
val contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
  this, // your Activity or 
  "com.example.myapp.fileprovider", // The android:authorities value from your manifest 
  file) // The File you want to store the video into
recordVideoResult.launch(contentUri)
```

4. Change your call to `registerForActivityResult` to account for the `success` Boolean result:

```
val recordVideoResult = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.CaptureVideo()) { success ->
    if (success) {
      // Now your file contains the fully captured video
    } else {
      // The user cancelled taking a video
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, probably never would have figured this out on my own. Thank you very much!